# How to fix mcast issue in gemfire caching system in a peer to peer set up

Tags: gemfire

I am using gemfire caching in a peer to peer set up. The system has been running fine with gemfire 6 for a number of years. I recently upgraded to gemfire 7 and get this error in agents and one of the processes-

```
[main] ERROR  [GemfirePeer] Issues while creating gemfire distributed region : com.gemstone.gemfire.IncompatibleSystemException: Rejected new system node because mcast was disabled which does not match the distributed system it is attempting to join. To fix this make sure the "mcast-port" gemfire property is set the same on all members of the same distributed system.
```

The mcast-port=0 is set in configuration properties in all processes.

Can someone please give ideas what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

This message means that there is at-least one member you have started that has the mcast-port set to a non-zero value, it potentially could be from your 6.x install as well. 
I would recommend that you use locator for member discovery.

Comment: I do use locators for member discovery. I just set mcast-port to 0 everywhere just to disable it.